# std::vector with a number in the second template parameter, can't find the definition on the c++ refernce

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I think I have asked this question long time ago, but can't find it.
I see this code snippet.

```
template <
    unsigned int N
    >
class pyramid_down : noncopyable
{
public:

    COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(N > 0);

    template <typename T>
    vector<double,2> point_down (
        const vector<T,2>& p
    ) const
    {
        const double ratio = (N-1.0)/N;
        return (p - 0.3)*ratio;
    }
```

the vector<double,2> seems to be a vector with two elments. Where can I find the c++ lenguage explanation for this?  I couldn't find it here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Where did you get that code from? Are you sure it's actually `std::vector`?

Comment: That snippet alone can't fully explain what's going on there.

Comment: The `std::vector` template has a second type that specifies an allocator type.   `std::vector<double, 2>` is not valid.    Your `vector` type, whatever it is, is some non-standard type that differs from `std::vector`

Comment: thanks all, it was dlib::vector from http://dlib.net

Comment: @ChanKim Why does your template not have stated `dlib::vector` instead of just `vector`?  You left your code wide open for these types of errors by not specifying the namespace.

Comment: You should probably go ahead and close the question as "not reproducible".

Comment: @cigien at the beginning of the program, there was namespace dlib {.  it was by my mistake not checking the namespace before(there is no using std). should I delete this question? I think it still provides some info to beginners that we should first check the namespace though.

Comment: It's up to you, but this issue is covered clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: yeah, but those who don't know there is 'different namespace' problem cannot search the web and arrive at the link you provided. I'd rather leave it at that so that people like me can get hint from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is not `std::vector`.

`std::vector` does not accept an integer in its 2nd template parameter, nor does it have an `operator-` defined, so clearly the `vector` in this example is not `std::vector` but is a different type of `vector`. Maybe a mathematical vector, or a graphical vector, who knows. There is no way to know from the limited snippet given.

Comment: yeah, right. I thought it's strange when I saw p -0.3 and should have looked in more. It was the vector in dlib.  `namespace dlib
{

    template <
        typename T,
        long NR = 3
        >
    class vector;`